# understanding of FPS and the methods they use

Tags: c++, c, actionscript-3, directx

Just looking on resources that break down how frames per second work. I know it has something to do with keeping track of Ticks and figure out how many ticks occured between each frame. But I never ran into any resources on why exactly you have to use the methods you use in order to get a smooth frame work. I am trying to get a thourough understanding of this. Can any explain or provide any good resources ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two approaches.

In ActionScript (and many other engines), you request the player to call a certain function at a certain framerate. For Flash games, you'll set the framerate to be 30 FPS, and then you'll implement a function that listens for ENTER_FRAME events to do what you need to do. This means you get roughly 33 ms per frame (1000ms/30FPS=33.33ms/frame). If your code that responds to ENTER_FRAME takes more than 33 ms, you'll get some stuttering.

In home-rolled main loops (like you'd generally do in C++/SDL, for example), you run the main loop as fast as possible. This means the time between each frame will be variable. You still need to keep the "guts" of your frame code less than 33 ms to make sure you'll get at least 30 FPS, but your game will run faster than 30 FPS if not a lot's going on. To account for this, you need to program all your logic in terms of elapsed time since last frame, and abandon using frames themselves as a unit of time.

Comment: Can you give an example of programming "_all your logic in terms of elapsed time since last frame, and abandon using frames themselves as a unit of time_"?

Answer (score 1):

http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/42624.aspx

[How do you separate game logic from display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411/how-do-you-separate-game-logic-from-display)

Answer (score 0):

For a continously variable frame rate you can measure the time the last frame took and assume *this* frame will take the same length of time.  This has the benefit of meaning that time runs more or less constantly.  Your biggest issue with this approach is that it is entirely possible for a VSync'd game to change from 60 fps to 30 fps and back again on subsequent frames.   From experience a good way to solve this is to average the last few frame times.  This smooths the result out.  In the 60 to 30 fps switch each frame will progress assuming 1/45 seconds and hence the 60fps frame run slow and the 30fps frame run fast and the perceived speed remains at 45fps.

Better still is to not use this sort of time step in your calculations.  Set yourself a minimum fps ... say 10fps.  You then calculate all your game logic at some multiple of these 1/10 second intervals.  The render engine then knows where the object is and where it is heading towards and so can inter/extrapolate the object position until its next "decision" frame shows up.  This has numerous advantages.  It decouples your logic entirely from rendering.  It allows you to spread the logic calculations over a number of frames.  For example, at 60Hz, you can test at what point a logic object will interesect with the world if it maintains its path every 6th frame.  This gives the bonus of allowing you to process some logic objects on different frames to spread calculation load across the time.  Its biggest disadvantage is that if the frame rate drops below your target rate everything slows down.